# How to export Plotly-generated interactive graph as HTML file from Jupyter Notebook using Python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I generated some **interactive graphs** using **Plotly** with Python in a Jupyter Notebook, but I couldn't seem to export them as **HTML** files. The export menu that was supposed to show up at the bottom-right corner, according to some thread online, just wasn't there.

The **workflow** of using Plotly with Python puzzles me. Can I write code to save interactive graphs to local drive automatically? Or do I have to use `chart_studio`? If so, how?

```py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = list()
COLORS = ["aqua","sienna","coral","darkgreen","darksalmon",
          "darkslateblue","greenyellow","maroon","violet"]

for county, col in zip(COUNTIES,COLORS):
    trace = go.Scatter(x = DF.columns,
                       y = DF.loc[county,:],
                       name = county,
                       line = dict(color = col),
                       opacity = 0.8)
    data.append(trace)

fig = go.Figure(data = data,
                layout = dict(title = "County-level (Normalized) Daily New Cases"))
fig.show()
```

[image: snapshot]]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is available in documentation see [here](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/)

```py
fig.write_html("path/to/file.html")
```

If you need to get a smaller footprint file and your file is going to be opened from a pc connected to internet you can use

```py
fig.write_html("path/to/file.html", include_plotlyjs="cdn")
```